# Insert blob firebird php

Tags: php, firebird, blob

eu estou com um problema ao tentar inserir um campo blob no firebird o meu código é o seguitne

```
    $ficheiro = $this->blob_create(file_get_contents($_FILES['ficheiro']['tmp_name']));
    $extensao = pathinfo($_FILES['ficheiro']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $nome = $_FILES['ficheiro']['name'];
    $size = intval($_FILES['ficheiro']['size']);


    $firebird->query("INSERT INTO DOCUMENTOS (ID_PAI, TIPO_PAI, FICHEIRO, DESCRICAO, TIPO_DOC, OBS, EXTENSAO, NOME_FICHEIRO, TAMANHO, DT_INSERCAO, DT_DOC) VALUES(".$this->db->escape($id).", ".$this->db->escape("MD_AGENDAMENTO").", ".$this->db->escape($ficheiro).", ".$this->db->escape($descricao).", ".$this->db->escape($tipo).", ".$this->db->escape($obs).", ".$this->db->escape(extensao).", ".$this->db->escape($nome).", ".$this->db->escape($size).", ".$this->db->escape(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")).", ".$this->db->escape($data).")");

public function blob_create($data) {
        if(strlen($data) == 0)
            return false;
        $handle = ibase_blob_create();
        $len = strlen($data);
        for ($pos = 0; $pos < $len; $pos += 65535) {
            $buflen = ($pos + 65535 > $len) ? ($len - $pos) : 65535;
            $buf = substr($data,$pos,$buflen);
            ibase_blob_add($handle,$buf);
        }

        return ibase_blob_close($handle);
    }
```

antes de inserir se eu fizer 
var_dump($ficheiro); die();
o resultado é 0x0000000100000000
se fizer
ibase_blob_echo($ficheiro);
o resultado é o ficheiro

mas depois de inserir quando faço o select e depois ibase_blob_echo($linha->FICHEIRO); obtenho o erro de que o id do blob é inválido..

Alguém sabe o que posso estar a fazer mal.

Desde já obrigado